# jsonschema - dynamic properties with static properties

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a schema to validate a json.

For certain properties i need them to have values of certain types.

- If "attr" property is "a" then "val" property should be "integer"
- If "attr" property is "x" then "val" property should be "boolean"
- If "attr" property is "b" then "val" property should be "string" with
  format "ipv4"

and so on...

This, I can define with oneOff. For all other "attr" properties i need to them to be of a certain format, sort of like a catch all, with "val" property to be "string".

- If "attr" matches pattern then "val" property should be "string".

can this be done.

This is the schema that i have at the moment.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "attribute": {
      "title": "attributes",
      "type": "object",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/expr",
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "expr": {
      "properties": {
        "attr": {
          "title": "attribute"
        },
        "val": {
          "title": "val"
        }
      },
      "required": ["val", "attr"],
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "attr": {"enum": ["a","b"]},
            "val": {"type": "integer"}
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "attr": {"enum": ["x"]},
            "val": {"type": "boolean"}
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "attr": {"pattern": "^[-A-Za-z0-9_]*$", "maxLength": 255},
            "val": {"type": "string"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "name",
    "attribute"
  ]
}
```

The problem is the properties for which i am trying to restrict the value type, also match the catchall format. so when i am expecting an integer value, it is passing with string value.

**For Example:**

the below json will pass the schema, based on the first item of oneOff

```
{
  "name": "shouldpass",
  "attribute": {
    "attr": "a",
    "val": 1
  }
}
```

the below json will pass, based on the last item of oneOff.

```
{
  "name": "shouldpass2",
  "attribute": {
    "attr": "h",
    "val": "asd"
  }
}
```

the below json should fail, based on the first item of oneOff, but it is also passing, because it is matching the last item of oneOff.

```
{
  "name": "shouldfail",
  "attribute": {
    "attr": "a",
    "val": "string"
  }
}
```

how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You schema for attr in the last subschema could be:

```
{
    "pattern": "^[-A-Za-z0-9_]*$",
    "not": { "enum": ["a", "b", "x"] },
    "maxLength": 255
}
```

Alternatively, instead of "oneOf" you can use "switch" keyword from the next JSON-schema version proposals: http://epoberezkin.github.io/ajv/keywords.html#switch-v5-proposal

It's implemented in Ajv (I am the author).